# Jquery - wildcard ID, Conditional value check fails if the first occurrence fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have the following simple HTML:

```
        <dl>
            <dt>Percentage</dt>
            <dd><input type="text" id="percentage1" value="20"/></dd>
            <dt>Description</dt>
            <dd><input type="text" id="wastetype1" value="Inert - Mixed"/></dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt>Percentage</dt>
            <dd><input type="text" id="percentage2" value="20"/></dd>
            <dt>Description</dt>
            <dd><input type="text" id="wastetype2" value="Brick"/></dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt>Percentage</dt>
            <dd><input type="text" id="percentage3" value="60"/></dd>
            <dt>Description</dt>
            <dd><input type="text" id="wastetype3" value="Concrete"/></dd>
        </dl>
```

I want to conditionally add the the values of those fields into an object using the following code:

```
if (($('[id^=percentage]').val().length > 0) || ($('[id^=wastetype]').val().length > 0)){
    var breakdownArray = [];
    $('[id^="percentage"]').each(function() {
        var thisId = $(this).attr('id').substring(10);
        if (($('#percentage'+thisId).val().length > 0) && ($('#wastetype'+thisId).val().length > 0)){
            var breakdownObject = {};
            breakdownObject.percentage = $('#percentage'+thisId).val();
            breakdownObject.description = $('#wastetype'+thisId).val();
            breakdownArray.push(breakdownObject);
        }
    });
    postData.breakdown = breakdownArray;
}
```

I am particularly vexed by the if statement

```
if (($('[id^=percentage]').val().length > 0) || ($('[id^=wastetype]').val().length > 0))
```

I was expecting this to pass the test if ANY of the field matching those Id's had values.

However, If percentage1 and wastetype1 are empty the whole 'if' statement fails, regardless of any other values in any other fields.

If I leave percentage3 and wastetype3 blank it works just fine.

It would seem that if the first set of fields are empty the whole thing fails but not of any of the others are empty?!?

Any help on would be appreciated.

Comment: Calling `val()` on a collection only reads the first element. If you want to check all the elements, then you will need to loop through them and check individually. Given your HTML it would be much easier to use common classes instead of the ids, then loop over each `dl` to check the values contained within it.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan - I take the point about the HTML, the example is a test set from another source so it might look a bit clunky without context. I will set up a loop and check the values. I was under the impression that using the wildcard as a selector would work, but it's obviously wishful thinking. I wanted to check that i was not doing something daft before I wrote a loop and behold - I was :)